# Accept any value in JavaScript? (Regular expression?)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a small very simple game.

I want to know how to accept any input value in the following code...

```
if(answer === "My name is" + * + "and I am a Leo" ) {
  alert("Correct!")
}
```

To my understanding the asterisks would accept any value input by the user.
Besides that, script breaks after i write the above.

Forgot to add the [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq4gjo85/)

Comment: You're confusing things like wildcarding with JavaScript, `*` in JavaScript is for multiplication.

Comment: Seems like you're looking to use a regular expression

Comment: You should probably show more of your code before we can help you properly.

Comment: @Popnoodles is there a character for this? Or do I have to create another variable?

Comment: @Mike someone who is good with regular expressions will answer... There are also other valid methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (answer.substring(0, 10) == "My name is" && answer.slice(-14) == "and I am a Leo") {
    alert("Correct!");
}
```

substring(0, 10) -> gets the first 10 characters
slice(-14) -> gets the last 14 characters

Here's a regex approach too:

```
var matches = answer.match(/^My name is (.*) and I am a Leo$/);
if (matches != null) {
    alert("Correct!"); //use matches[1] to get the name
}
```

Comment: Why not use test? It's less confusing

Comment: You forgot to anchor the regexp.

Comment: It doesn't grab the name. This is going to be a game, where saving the name/using the name in some fashion is going to be required.

Comment: Thank You - the Regex approach worked very well and was simple. I would like to learn the logic to the substring approach though. Thanks for explaining that to me.

Comment: @vihan What do you mean? Could you explain to me how to do it with the test method?

Comment: @Mike using: `if (/^My name is .* and I am a Leo$/.test(answer)`

Comment: @torazaburo I guess I did. I've added it so it only works on one line only.  at Mike, it's the same thing, but it returns true/false instead. It's better to use test if you don't intend on grabbing the name.

Comment: @DaveChen Thanks for that - I do not intend to grab the name. This is actually testing html which will have tags. Will this change the way I write my code?

Comment: If you don't want the name, then yep using `if (answer.test(...))` would be better :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already prompted the user for a value to the `answer` variable.

You probobly want to use a regeular expression:

```
if (answer.search(/^My name is.*and I am a Leo$/) === 0) {
    alert("Correct!");
}
```

Look at this [cheatsheet](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/javascript) to see what the difference characters mean. The search method returns the position of the match in the string, or -1 at failure. In this case, since `^` matches the start of the string, it will always return 0 on success.

`$` matches the end of the string and `.*` means match any character except newline 0 or more times (that is any amount of times).